# JavaScript failed to create QT object

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I am creating QT object in Java script & emitting signal from JavaScript to QML Slot.

My work Environment : **Qt 5.8 MSVC2015 64bit, Windows 7 64 bit.**

Code testJava.js :

```
var internalQmlObject = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.5; \
                                            QtObject { \
                                                signal someSignal(int value) \
                                            }',
                                           Qt.application,
                                           'InternalQmlObject');
function runNow(){
    internalQmlObject.someSignal(42);
}
```

Code of QML :

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtWebEngine 1.4
import "testJava.js" as Helper
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 1024
    height: 750
    visible: true

    WebEngineView {
        id: webEngine
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "qrc:/TestPage.html"

        function someSlot(v) {
            console.log("Signal received " + v);
        }

        onLoadingChanged: {
            Helper.internalQmlObject.someSignal.connect(someSlot);
        }
    }
}
```

But Java Script failed to create QtQuick 2.5 object:

> Starting D:\task\QT_Test\build-testURL-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\testURL.exe...
>
> js: Uncaught ReferenceError: Qt is not defined
>
> [4492:5796:0427/113341:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] **"Uncaught ReferenceError: Qt is not defined", source: qrc:/testJava.js (1)**

Any suggestion why JavaScript failed to identify QT?

Comment: I have tested the code and have not had any problems. You could try my [code](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/JSTestingQt).

Comment: I can't confirm that behavior with `qt5.7.1/qtquick2.7`

Comment: I found the issue, in HTML page, I am loading testJava.js, which causing this issue :  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="testJava.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: I needed to add src="testJava.js" in HTML page,  Then only I can handle JavaScript singal into my QML.

Answer (score 0):

I found work around, create javascript file & load it object as below :

import "testJava.js" as Helper

But it should not be a ideal solution QML.